# Как определить колонку с типом данных BLOB в приватной временной таблице (PTT)?

Tags: sql, oracle, blob, oracle19c

При написании различных процедур столкнулся с проблемой, что когда пытаюсь в приватной временной таблице (PTT) определить колонку с типом данных `BLOB`, вот так:

```sql
create private temporary table ora$ptt_test (
    id number, userdata blob);
```

То получаю ошибку:

> ORA-14451: unsupported feature with temporary table
>   14451. 00000 -  "unsupported feature with temporary table"
>   *Cause:    An attempt was made to create an IOT, specify physical attributes,
>              specify partition or parallel clause.
>   *Action:   do not do that.

Если закомментировать колонку `userdata`, то выполнится без ошибок.

Всё, что смог найти в документации, что в основном ограничения при создании PTT те же самые, как для публичных временных таблиц (GTT). Но это не совсем соответствует действительности, потому что попробовал создать публичную временную таблицу с `BLOB` колонкой - никаких ошибок, так работает.

<sub>Свободный перевод [How to define BLOB column in Private Temporary Table?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53173393/6571020) от участника [@Gregor Cerinšek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7756682/gregor-cerin%c5%a1ek)</sub>

Comment: ассоциаця:https://stackoverflow.com/q/53173393/6571020

Answer (score 2):

Воспроизводится также для `CLOB` колонок. Скорее всего баг в [документации (см. PRIVATE TEMPORARY)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6).

Основная особенность приватныx временных таблиц то, что они создаются как структуры данных в памяти, конкретно в памяти сессии PGA (*Program Global Area*). Возможно есть сложности с управлением структурами памяти для LOB типов данных. Несколько похоже на проблематику: [creating a PTT in a PDB with the in-memory option enabled](https://exagriddba.wordpress.com/2018/02/18/notes-on-private-temporary-tables/).

Но с другой стороны, можно же создавать коллекции с LOB типами данных в PL/SQL, которые используют те же самые структуры памяти. И кроме того, сами LOB типы данных состоят из двух частей, локатора (*LOB locator*, своего рода ссылка), и собственно данных (*value*), а в колонке таблицы сохраняется как раз только локатор. Так что, не видно серьёзных барьеров связанных с обработкой LOB типов данных в памяти.

Исходя из вышеизложенного, возможно имеет место только временное ограничение, которое будет устранено в последующих релизах. Конечно это не решает проблему, поэтому остаётся предложить обратиться в тех. подержку *Oracle*, а пока пользоваться публичными временными таблицами:

```sql
create global temporary table gtt_test (
    id number, userdata blob);

Global temporary TABLE created.
```

<sub>Свободный перевод и доработка [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53174300/6571020) от участника [@APC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/146325/apc)</sub>